# Liaison étrange avec « aller » ?

Tags: régionalismes, accents-régionaux

Il y a longtemps j’ai regardé une vidéo où quelqu’un a dit « Aller avec » avec une liaison. C’était prononcé comme « allé ravec » et c’était très bizarre.

J’ai demandé à ma prof de français et elle était perdue et aussi mon ami français et il a dit que c’était peut-être quelqu’un de la Suisse de la Belgique.

Est-ce qu’il y a une raison pour ça ? Ou c’etait juste quelque chose d’aléatoire sans une bonne raison ?

Comment: you’re right, thanks!

Comment: Certaines liaisons (comme "aller-r-avec") devraient être faites mais ne le sont plus vraiment.